# Periodically edit a Rails database from a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have been working with and learning Rails for a few months and have recently taken up a project that calls for a gem that will periodically pull data from another site and compile it into a database friendly format.

I have the ruby code to do the pulling, editing, and formatting. My question is how to get the gem to edit the database for the Rails app that will be built by inserting the data. What I want is to have a few models based off the data being mined by the gem.

Some background info on the app. The app will be a stats reporting app for sports. So the models that are based on the data mined will be Stats, Players, Teams, and Games. There will be other models in the application as well, such as Devise users and others.

Once again, I have made the ruby code that will pull the data using 'json' and 'nokogiri' gems and will put them into (a lot of) hashes. I just have no idea how to store them in a database usable by a Rails app. Or any database for that matter. The only information I could turn up had to do with Engines and Railtie but there were no thorough explanations.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The simple way is to use CSV format, it is used to seed the DB with a data. Of course you can seed the DB with not plain text data: like string, integers, etc. but with the hashes (even JSON-like format). However for it you need the specific gem, and to use postgresql

Comment: @majioa I have the ability already to put the data scraped into any format I want so that it is "database-able", the question I would like answered is how to _access_ a database from a gem. Preferably the same database could be used (eventually) by a rails application. Thanks for the reply though.